# Why am I getting the error "Invalid upload source" When attempting to upload a folder from my C drive with B2's CLI tool

Tags: windows, backup, backblaze

I am attempting to upload a folder with the server data from a game server from my C drive with the "upload-file" command using B2's windows CLI. Every time I try, I am returned with the error "Invalid upload source". I will post the command below but not put the actual bucket name.

```
b2 upload-file BUCKET_NAME C:\Servers BKUPTest
```

Answer (score 1):

`b2 upload-file` uploads one file to the given bucket, hence it is complaining that its source is a folder rather than a single file.

Use `b2 sync C:\Servers b2://BUCKET_NAME/BKUPTest/`